# Only seeing 'COMMITTING' from getPendingTransactions and never 'COMMIT_FAILED'?

Tags: relayjs

I am trying to set up retries, on failed mutations, as documented by Relay: https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-container.html#getpendingtransactions.

I am causing the mutation to fail, on the graphql server, by returning an error:

```
 mutateAndGetPayload: ({text}) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(new Error("failed"));
      }, 2 * 1000);
    });
  },
```

When I first execute the mutation I can see the status of 'COMMITTING'. But then in the next render getPendingTransactions returns null and I cannot figure out how to see a status of 'COMMIT_FAILED'.

```
var transactions = this.props.relay.getPendingTransactions(this.props.story);

console.log("TRANSACTIONS", transactions);

var transaction = transactions ? transactions[0] : null;

if (transaction) {
  console.log("STATUS", transaction.getStatus());
}
```

I must be missing something, but so far can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your transaction with a `COMMIT_FAILED` will not be in `pendingTransactions` since it has been tried and failed already. Are you mutating using `RelayStore.update` ?

You could try creating a transaction using `RelayStore.apply_update`. This function actually returns the transaction object. You can then call `transaction.commit()`. If it fails, your transaction object should have a status of `COMMIT_FAILED`.

Comment: Yes, I see that does return the transaction and I can get the status from it. I also see that I can pass callbacks to either RelayStore.update or RelayStore.appyUpdate and I can get the transaction in the failure callback and call transaction.recommit() there... I'm still not sure how Relay expects it to work like the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-container.html#getpendingtransactions Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Oh I had not seen this part of the doc. Maybe I'm wrong that it should'nt be in `pendingTransaction` then. Good to know that it worked with `apply_update`!